# Why is SqlContext serializable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As per my understanding of spark, sparkContext/hiveContext/sqlContext shouldn't be sent to executors. But I would like to know why [SQLContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala) is a Serializable class?